# Xcode 5: 'xcodebuild' fails even on 'Empty Application' template

Tags: gcc, xcode5, xcodebuild

[Issues between `xcodebuild` and `Jenkins`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416900/restkit-restkit-h-file-not-found-error-during-xcodebuild) prompted me to try `xcodebuild` on a vanilla `Empty Application` template where it *still* fails:

```
>> xcodebuild -target FizzBuzz -sdk iphonesimulator7.0 -arch i386
The following build commands failed:
ProcessPCH /var/folders/64/<someHash>/C/com.apple.DeveloperTools/5.0-5A1413/\
Xcode/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/FizzBuzz-Prefix-<someHash>/FizzBuzz-Prefix.pch.pch
FizzBuzz/FizzBuzz-Prefix.pch 
normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

>> xcodebuild -version
Xcode 5.0
Build version 5A1413
```

**What is the proper incantation of `xcodebuild`?**

Comment: I don't know why? But mb just setup Command Line tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These 3 were the key issues for me:

1. `xcodebuild` was still relying on `gcc-4.7` (`Command Line Tools` installed or not). Check `$CC` and `unset $CC` to let `clang` do its job.
2. Use the `-scheme` option with `xcodebuild` ...
3. ... and `ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=NO`.