# Introducing Swift in OC Project Causes archive Error with xcodebuild, and use xcode will be ok

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcodebuild

I am trying create CI for my project using jenkins. Build is failing continuously because of the below mentioned issue. I have integrated charts as mentioned in USAGE tab. I can also reproduce the issue using terminal with 'XCODEBUILD' command.

and CI:

```
xcodebuild archive -scheme TeCharts1 -configuration Debug -archivePath /Users/xxxx/Desktop/test/test.xcarchive clean archive
```

Configuration details:

xcode 9.4.1

swift 4

Objective c project

fatal error:

```
'Charts/Charts.h' file not found

#import <Charts/Charts.h>
^
1 error generated.
```

[error1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtiPk.jpg)

[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpinT.jpg)

I can use xcode to generate ipa.  It took me a long time to look for an answer in google and stack overflow and i counld't find the answer.I have no idea. Please help me.

Comment: I guess you add the Charts via Cocoapods. And when you run your jenkins, you forgot to pod install. So it can't found your Charts

Comment: @ Quoc Nguyen 
i didn't use Cocoapods.

In order to correctly compile:

Drag the Charts.xcodeproj to your project
Go to your target's settings, hit the "+" under the "Embedded Binaries" section, and select the Charts.framework
@import Charts
When using Swift in an ObjC project:
You need to import your Bridging Header. Usually it is "YourProject-Swift.h", so in ChartsDemo it's "ChartsDemo-Swift.h". Do not try to actually include "ChartsDemo-Swift.h" in your project :-)
(Xcode 8.2+) Under "Build Options", mark "Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries"

i did this.

Comment: yeah, sorry about it

Comment: Still very grateful

Comment: I found some one has same problem, you can check it here, hope it help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416900/restkit-restkit-h-file-not-found-error-during-xcodebuild

Comment: The problem is not solved, I think it is a problem with the module of charts, I am replacing chart with PNChart